# (編集回数) revs, (編集したユーザー数) users **%の"**%"って何？

Tags: サポート, コミュニティwiki

コミュニティWikiの質問には次のように書いてあります。

> (編集回数) revs, (編集したユーザー数) users **%

この"**%"って何でしょうか？(**は数字)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (編集回数) revs, (編集したユーザー数) users **%

の次の行に最も Wiki を編集しているユーザーが表示されています。
「**％」はそのユーザーの編集が Wiki に占める割合と思われます。

根拠は無いですが体験上はこうなっています。
参考: [What does the % in the Community Wiki box mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190204/what-does-the-in-the-community-wiki-box-mean)
表記変更の要望: [Community wiki revision and user links separation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287389)